# Ajax call returns an array of empty objects

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oop

Am using OOP of php,am fetching data from the database.
data is fetched well but when i make ajax calls , it returns an array of empty objects. how can to make  objects return the data

**fetched database results before json_encoding it**

```
Array ( [0] => CategoryModel Object ( [id:CategoryModel:private] => 1 [code:CategoryModel:private] => cat001 [name:CategoryModel:private] => laptop [date:CategoryModel:private] => 2018-11-05 15:33:21 [owner:CategoryModel:private] => OwnerModel Object ( [companyName:OwnerModel:private] => [id:PersonModel:private] => 1 [code:PersonModel:private] => [firstname:PersonModel:private] => [lastname:PersonModel:private] => [username:PersonModel:private] => [email:PersonModel:private] => [password:PersonModel:private] => [date:PersonModel:private] => [mobile:PersonModel:private] => [fullname:PersonModel:private] => Galiwango Fahad [account_type:PersonModel:private] => ) [status:CategoryModel:private] => 0 ) [1] => CategoryModel Object ( [id:CategoryModel:private] => 2 [code:CategoryModel:private] => cat002 [name:CategoryModel:private] => pen [date:CategoryModel:private] => 2018-11-05 16:05:29 [owner:CategoryModel:private] => OwnerModel Object ( [companyName:OwnerModel:private] => [id:PersonModel:private] => 1 [code:PersonModel:private] => [firstname:PersonModel:private] => [lastname:PersonModel:private] => [username:PersonModel:private] => [email:PersonModel:private] => [password:PersonModel:private] => [date:PersonModel:private] => [mobile:PersonModel:private] => [fullname:PersonModel:private] => Galiwango Fahad [account_type:PersonModel:private] => ) [status:CategoryModel:private] => 0 ) )
```

**php code** *that retrieves and encodes the data*

```
<?php

require_once("../services/CategoryService.php");
$categoryService = new CategoryService();
$categoryArray =  $categoryService->selectAllCategoryDetails();
if(count($categoryArray)>0){
// echo print_r($categoryArray);
  echo json_encode($categoryArray);


}else{
  echo 0;
}

?>
```

**javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ".././com.flex_audit/controllers/fetchAllCategoriesController.php",
    data: "",

    success: function (responseData) {
        if(responseData!=0){
            var categoryObjArr = JSON.parse(responseData);
            console.log(categoryObjArr);
            console.log(categoryObjArr[0]);
            console.log(categoryObjArr[0]["id"]);
        }else{
            $("#alertMessage").text(" categories not found ");
        }
       // console.log(responseData);    
    }
    ,
    error:function(error){
      alert("an error occured "+error);
    }
});

  });
```

**console result**

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 {}
 undefined
```

why is that the response returns empty objects

Comment: Because all properties of your objects are __private__.

Comment: it now working, but is there any other way than making my class properties public

Comment: Implement http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because all properties of the objects are private**
 *it worked after making class properties public instead of private *

*from*

```
private $id,$code,$name,$date,$owner,$status;
```

*to*

```
public $id,$code,$name,$date,$owner,$status;
```